# Finding cell after column insert in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've been looking for a way to find a cell after it moves one column from an insert. This has been difficult to automate since values will change cells (but will keep the same row) and my "IF" statements will not be correct.
The attached image is an example of the cell moving one column.

[image]

Any way to track a value consistently in VBA after it changes cells?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the last filled column and then use offset property to fill values.

```
Sub ChangingColumn()
Dim lastcolumn As Long
lastcolumn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Assumning that you are testing in 10th row
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(DesiredRow,lastcolumn).offset(0,2).value = NewRevenueValue
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(DesiredRow,lastcolumn).offset(0,3).value = PayoutTierValue
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(DesiredRow,lastcolumn).offset(0,4).value = NewTotalPayValue
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.name) for the cell:

```
Sub test1()
    Const CELL_NAME = "NewRevenue"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add CELL_NAME, Range("AA10")
    Debug.Print "Address before moving: " & Range(CELL_NAME).Address
    Columns("AA").Insert
    Rows(10).Insert
    Debug.Print "Address after moving: " & Range(CELL_NAME).Address
End Sub
```

Output:

```
Address before moving: $AA$10
Address after moving: $AB$11
```